# Get RequestBody List<Enum> instead of RequestBody List<String> with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, enums, request

I have this endpoint

```
  @PUT
  @Path("/rolesV2/{queriedUserId}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response update(@HeaderParam("authToken") String authToken, @HeaderParam("userLoginId") Long userLoginId, @PathParam("queriedUserId") Long queriedUserId, @RequestBody List<Enum> rolesV2)
```

I can receive an

```
RequestBody List<String> = {"VALUE1", "VALUE2"}
```

I have this enum

```
public enum Enum {
  VALUE1,
  VALUE2;

  @JsonCreator
  public static Enum fromString(String val) {
    for (Enum role : Enum.values()) {
      if (val.equals(role.name()) || val.equals(role.toString())) {
        return role;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

But when i try to do:

```
RequestBody List<Enum>
```

instead of

```
RequestBody List<String>
```

I get an array with null values.
Is it possible to receive directly the enum, or do I have to apply the transformation manually ?

Thanks!

[FIRST EDIT]

Here's the exact enum

```
public enum UserLoginRoleV2 {
  [...]

  SETTINGS(true, UserLoginRoleType.BASIC),
  PROFILE(false, UserLoginRoleType.BASIC),
  BILLING(true, UserLoginRoleType.BASIC),
  SUB_USERS(true, UserLoginRoleType.BASIC),
  CONNECTED_ACCOUNTS(true, UserLoginRoleType.BASIC),
  INTEGRATIONS(true, UserLoginRoleType.BASIC),
  TRACKING_SETTINGS(true, UserLoginRoleType.BASIC),
  TRACKING_DOMAINS(true, UserLoginRoleType.BASIC),

  ADMIN(false, UserLoginRoleType.BASIC),
  SUPER_ADMIN(false, UserLoginRoleType.BASIC),

  AGENCY(true, UserLoginRoleType.AGENCY);

  /** Enables assigning this role from Admin Panel */
  private boolean assignable;

  private UserLoginRoleType type;

  UserLoginRoleV2(boolean assignable, UserLoginRoleType type) {
    this.assignable = assignable;
    this.type = type;
  }

  public boolean isBasic() {
    return this.type.equals(UserLoginRoleType.BASIC);
  }

  public boolean isAgency() {
    return this.type.equals(UserLoginRoleType.AGENCY);
  }

  public boolean isAssignable() {
    return assignable;
  }

  public void setAssignable(boolean assignable) {
    this.assignable = assignable;
  }

  public UserLoginRoleType getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(UserLoginRoleType type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static UserLoginRoleV2 fromString(String val) {
    for (UserLoginRoleV2 role : UserLoginRoleV2.values()) {
      if (val.equals(role.name()) || val.equals(role.toString())) {
        return role;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static List<UserLoginRoleV2> getNewAgencyRoles() {
    return Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(UserLoginRoleV2.values()).filter(UserLoginRoleV2::isAgency), Stream.of(SUB_USERS, BILLING, CONNECTED_ACCOUNTS)).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  public static List<UserLoginRoleV2> getBasicRoles() {
    return Arrays.stream(UserLoginRoleV2.values()).filter(UserLoginRoleV2::isBasic).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

And I can confirm that I receive an array like :

["BILLING", "SETTINGS"]

Comment: Are you sure you getting exact those values? No extra spaces or other stuff?

Comment: I updated what I receive when I put "RequestBody List<String" and the exact enum I have.

Comment: your don't have any issues in json creator, but can you try `UserLoginRoleV2.valueOf(val)`

Comment: I thought Spring Boot can automatically map enums, even without implementing a custom jsoncreator. Do you need the custom conversion?

Comment: If you meant 
  @JsonCreator
  public static UserLoginRoleV2 fromString(String val) {
    return UserLoginRoleV2.valueOf(val);
  } it didnt work

Comment: @knittl it doesn't work with the default one either